# Java: How to construct derived class instance given base instance?

Tags: java

Given:

```
@lombok.Data // generates get/set methods for all data members
public class Base {
    private int x;
    private double y;
    private String z;
    ...
}


public class Derived extends Base {
    private int extra;
    public String addedMethod() { ... }
}
```

I want to write:

```
Derived createDerived(Base baseInstance, int extra) { ... }
```

to produce an instance of Derived that has the same Base property values as 'baseInstance'.

What is the most effective way to do this if:

1. Both Base and Derived are open for modification
2. Base is closed but Derived is open

I would like avoid explicitly enumerating the members of Base in the Derived code like this:

```
    Derived createDerived(Base b, int extra) {
      setX(b.getX());
      setY(b.getY());
      setZ(b.getZ());
      ...
      this.extra = extra;
    }
```

or this:

```
Derived createDerived(Base b, int extra) {
    super(b.getX(), b.getY(), b.getY(), ...);
    this.extra = extra;
}
```

Any addition to Base then breaks the Derived class code.

Something like this would be preferable, using a hypothesized copy constructor for Base:

```
    Derived createDerived(Base b, int extra) {
      super(b);
      this.extra = extra;
    }
```

What is the best way to produce that copy constructor? Again it would be preferable to avoid enumerating each member of Base.

Comment: ... *why* do you want to do this?  Done correctly you'd have access to all of the parent class' fields in your child class.

Comment: I don't get the question. Can you extend the example? Describe the scenario in more detail?

Comment: I don't even understand what `extend` is suppose to do.  Can you show us some code?  Can you at least describe what the result of calling `extends()` is?

Answer (score 3):

If `Base` can be modified, I'd add a copy constructor and call it from `Derived`:

```
class Base {
    int field;

    Base(int field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    Base(Base base) {
        this(base.field);
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    int extra;

    Derived(Base base, int extra) {
        super(base);
        this.extra = extra;
    }
}
```

If you can't modify `Base`, you can still pass an instance to `Derived` and then copy each field individually through `super`:

```
Derived(Base base, int extra) {
    super(base.field, extra);
}
```